# Read Environment Variable from all processes

Tags: python, windows, process, environment-variables

I've got some quession about environment variables. I want to read and print environment variables to each processes in Windows system.
But I`ve got a problem with it. I use Python, module "pywin32".

Result of this code:

```
import win32profile
import pprint

env_var = win32profile.GetEnvironmentStrings()
pprint.pprint(env_var)
```

is getting EnVars to current process. I find example in C, but I can't do this in python.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the example you found in C?

Comment: Yes, of course!
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25647/Read-Environment-Strings-of-Remote-Process

Comment: If that C code build on top of the win32 API, you can use ctypes to achieve the same in Python.